# how I can exit or break a command in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to know if there is a way to break a command when it matches a condition

for example i want to break this command when user is not admin

```
@client.command
async def test_me(ctx):
    user = ctx.author.id
    if user not in admins:
       await ctx.send("you're not admin")
       break command 
    else:
       None
    await ctx.send('Hi admin')
```

so i don't want to add the whole thing in a if statement that's why I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `break` a function. You need to be in a loop to use break, also you don't need the `else` statement if it is empty.

If you just want to exit the function you can use `return`

Something like this should work

```
@client.command
async def test_me(ctx):
    user = ctx.author.id
    if user not in admins:
       await ctx.send("you're not admin")
       return 
    await ctx.send('Hi admin')
```

Comment: This is a solution but not the best solution

Comment: @bravosierra99 i never said this was the best one. I have 0 experience with discord, I only answered from a  general python perspective

Comment: That’s fine. Just letting you know for the future.

Comment: @bravosierra99 Hello. What is the best solution?

Comment: @Tatuck look at my solution below

Answer (score 0):

They have a built in system for requiring permissions

```
@commands.has_guild_permissions(manage_roles=True)
```

Simply replace the permissions with administrator and place this decorator on your functions.

Here is how I’ve used it

```
@commands.bot_has_guild_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def remove(
        self, ctx, roles: Greedy[RoleConverter], members: Greedy[MemberConverter]
    ):
```

Comment: My example is for ensuring the bot has permissions. The first chunk of code is for when the user must have the permission