# How do i "goto" the next step?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="TOS Agreement!", color=0x38ffa9)
        embed.add_field(name="What you're agreeing to", value="By using this service you agree that you are at least 18 years old and have the right to send the required data to this bot, and agree that the data may be stored on a database so that your profile can be shared to others and that your profile will be public!\n\nDo you agree? Options: Yes, No", inline=False)
        question = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await question.add_reaction("")
        await question.add_reaction("")
        
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["▶️", "♂️", "♀️", "♂️", "", "", "", "❌", ""]

        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=1800, check=check)
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
                    await ctx.send("Cancel")
                    break
                if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
                    await ctx.send("TOS Accepted")
                    await question.delete()

            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await question.delete()
                break
```

There will be new reactions to add and a new question to ask.. after  has been used, how do i print a new question and wait for the new reactions? i've tried many ways and it just doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```py
questions = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3"]
for question in questions:
    message = await ctx.send(question)
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
    try:
        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=1800, check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji in ["", ""])
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            await ctx.send("Cancel")
            break
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        break
else:
    await ctx.send("TOS Accepted")
    await message.delete()
```

You can specify your questions list in the code. And bot will ask them in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Ratery has a good answer, but I have one that may be of use as well. Since these commands are functions, you can easily use `return` to end a function where it is at the moment. `break` exits your `while True` loop instead of ending the command. Please do view the revised code and working example below.

```py
while True:
    try:
        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=1800, check=check)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            await ctx.send("Cancel")
            return # Ends the command entirely, does not continue after loop
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
           await ctx.send("TOS Accepted")
           await question.delete()
           break # Ends loop and goes to the next part ("Next question...")

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await question.delete()
        return # Ends the command entirely, does not continue after loop

# do other things here
await ctx.send("Next question...")
```

[image: Command working in testing]

**Useful Link(s)**:

- [How I can exit or break a command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63280243/how-i-can-exit-or-break-a-command-in-discord-py) - Stackoverflow